# Probability of a subsequence being drawn from a known distribution

Tags: likelihood

Let $X_i$ where $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ be discrete i.i.d. random variables with a known density, i.e. $X_i \sim f(x)$ and let the sequence $S_i$ be a realization. How does one quantify the extent to which the empirical distribution implied by $S_i$, or a subsequence $S_i'$ of $S_i$ fits the known distribution $f$?

This question arises when one wants to construct a random graph with a given degree sequence $S_i$ that is connected. If this fails, then one option may be to just pick the largest connected component (giant component), hence arriving at a degree subsequence $S_i'$

Comment: I don't follow: first, why use $i$ to index the name of the sequence? Second, conditional on a given sequence, a subsequence has either probability $0$ or $1,$ depending on whether it occurs in $S_i.$

Comment: @whuber I was thinking about the likelihood of the subsequence being drawn from $f$...

Comment: What role, then, does $S_i$ play?  Since you posit the $X_i$ are *iid,* then by definition the chance of a given subsequence is the product of the chances of its components.

Comment: @whuber I see what you mean. I have rephrased the question. Maybe you will have one more look :)

Comment: That's clearer now.  Search our site for "chi-squared test" for one common approach.

Comment: Very useful, thanks!